# How to make jQuery UI Slider smoother when the step is 0.25

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I know that we can change the step in short distance between `min` and `max` and `Math round` the UI value to create smooth sliding like

```
step: .0001, 
 ...
$(".value").text("slider value: " + Math.round(ui.value));
```

but this is OK when the step is `1`. How about this case which is `0.25`. How can I make the slider smoother?

```js
$( function() {
    var handle = $( "#custom-handle" );
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
    min:-12,
    max:6,
    step:0.25,
      create: function() {
        handle.text( $( this ).slider( "value" ) );
      },
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        handle.text( ui.value.toFixed(2) );
      }
    });
  } );
```

```css
 body{
  padding:60px;
  }

#slider 
{
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 1em;
}
 #custom-handle {
    width: 3em;
    height: 1.6em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -.8em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.6em;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">

<div id="slider">
 <div id="custom-handle" class="ui-slider-handle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code and description, you'd like the slider to actually step a smaller amount, such as .0001, yet show in steps of .25. For example if the current value was `-1.00`, and the user moved the slider leftward, the actual value would reduce by .0001 each step, and the shown value should retain `-1.25`. Since we're working with `.25`, it may be best to step at `.05`. You'll see why later.

Basically, we need a better Math function or our own Rounding method. Something that fits this

```
+-------------+
| x    | r(x) |
+-------------+
| 1.00 | 1.00 |
| 1.05 | 1.00 |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| 1.20 | 1.00 |
| 1.25 | 1.25 |
| 1.30 | 1.25 |
+-------------+
```

```js
$(function() {
  var handle = $("#custom-handle");

  function rounding(l) {
    if (l == 0) {
      return 0.001;
    }
    var neg = false;
    var result = false;
    if (l < 0) {
      l = Math.abs(l);
      neg = true;
    }
    var i = Math.floor(l);
    var d = l - i;
    if (d % .25 == 0) {
      result = i + d;
    }
    if (neg) {
      result = 0 - result;
    }
    return result;
  }

  $("#slider").slider({
    min: -12,
    max: 6,
    step: 0.05,
    create: function() {
      handle.text($(this).slider("value"));
    },
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $(".raw").html(ui.value);
      var v = rounding(ui.value);
      $(".format").html(v);
      if (v) {
        handle.text(v.toFixed(2));
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 60px;
}

#slider {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

#custom-handle {
  width: 3em;
  height: 1.6em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -.8em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">

<div id="slider">
  <div id="custom-handle" class="ui-slider-handle"></div>
</div>
<div class="raw"></div>
<div class="format"></div>
```

To examine just the decimal, we can break our Long `1.25` into an Integer (`i`) would be `1` and Decimal (`d`) would be `.25`. We can then use Modulo `d % .25`, this will return just the remainder. E.G.: `.26 % .25 = .01`

This will work in most all cases except for `0`, `0 % .25 = 0` is true, but if we then return `0`, logically it will be read as `false`. So we just return a slightly more than zero value so it's read as a Long and then `.toFixed()` handles the rest.

If the User yanks the handle, it may skip the needed value and land in a position that would not update the handle. This happens even more so when the value step is `.01` or `.001`. Either the value gets skipped to allow for faster action or something can't keep up.

Hope that helps.